# Querying data with pg-cursor

Tags: javascript, node-postgres, pg-cursor

I have the following code to read the first 10 rows from a query with a PG Cursor in a CloudFlare worker:

```js
const client = new Client(`<DATABASE URL>`)
await client.connect()
const cursor = client.query(new Cursor(queryString))
let rows = await cursor.read(10)
cursor.close(() => client.release())
```

However, this is returning the following:

```
ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined
    at Cursor2._sendRows (file:///Users/neil/code/console-query-runner/node_modules/pg-cursor/index.js:120:5)
    at Cursor2.handlePortalSuspended (file:///Users/neil/code/console-query-runner/node_modules/pg-cursor/index.js:140:10)
    at Client2._handlePortalSuspended (file:///Users/neil/code/console-query-runner/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:372:22)
    at emitOne (node-modules-polyfills:events:84:13)
    at Connection.emit2 [as emit] (node-modules-polyfills:events:171:7)
...
```

From doing some digging it seems `setImmediate` is some built in Node-ism which isn't available in CF Workers by default somehow. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to shim `setImmediate` in this instances:

```bash
$ npm i setimmediate
```

then `require('setimmediate')` as early as possible in your app.